# push seconds to countdown timer

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nstimer, countdown

i create a countdown timer that display on a label, now i want to add an function that eberytime the user press on a button it will add 30 seconds to the countdown timer.
i tried to do it by myself but i didn't success(i got an error and one time it stop my timer) how can i do it?
here is my code:

```
-(IBAction)start:(id)sender
{
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.01 target:self     selector:@selector(updateTimer:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}

-(void)updateTimer:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    currentTime -= 10 ;
    [self populateLabelwithTime:currentTime];

    if(currentTime <=0)
    {
        [timer invalidate];
        //some code when countdown reach to 00:00:00
    }

}


- (void)populateLabelwithTime:(int)milliseconds {
    seconds = milliseconds/1000;
    minutes = seconds / 60;


    seconds -= minutes * 60;

    NSString * countdownText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%02d:%02d:%02d", (milliseconds<0?@"-":@""), minutes, seconds,milliseconds%1000];
    countdownLabel.text = countdownText;

}

-(IBAction)addTime:(id)sender
{
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.01 target:self selector:@selector(addToCurrent:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void) addToCurrent:(NSTimer *)timerb;
{
    seconds +=10;
    [self populateLabelWithTime:seconds];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    currentTime = 2700;

}
```

thanks!

Comment: It's helpful to include exactly what went wrong and what the error you got was.

Comment: `-(IBAction)addTime:(id)sender { currentTime += 30000; }`

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to recreate the timer with every button click.  Also, it looks to me like you're accidentally modifying seconds instead of currentTime when you try to add 30 seconds back to the timer.

```
-(IBAction)addTime:(id)sender
{
    currentTime += 30000;
    [self populateLabelWithTime:currentTime];
}
```